# How to live preview a set of files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, adobe-brackets, plunker, live-preview

I want to build a simple online editor like [plunker](https://github.com/filearts/plunker). Does anyone know how to accomplish the live preview, once several files (`.html`, `.css`, `.js`, `.json`) have been uploaded?

Taking JSBin as example, there are only 1 html text, 1 css text and 1 js text, so it is simple: we just need to construct one complete html file from these texts and use [Document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

However, how do editors such as `plunker`, `brackets`, `vscode` do live preview? Do they also construct one complete file by themselves or they use some third-party tools?

Comment: Ajax and Websockets. Just like StackOverflow.

Comment: I think StackOverflow is like JSBin, right? we could just merge the 3 texts to construct one complete html... But those editors are different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live previews are pretty easy. Just replace the HTML of an area on the page with the HTML the user provided. In practice, you probably want to do this in a sandboxed `iframe` for security purposes.

The snippet below shows how this can be done, all in JavaScript. Try running the snippet and typing in the box.

```js
function doLivePreview() {
  $("#output").html($("#source").val());
}

$(function() {
  doLivePreview();
  $("#source").on("input", doLivePreview);
});
```

```css
#source {
  float: left;
}

#output {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="source" cols="50" rows="8">
Type to see a live preview
<br/>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google<a>
</textarea>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: But this is what I said about JSBin, right? I am asking about how to handle files (with file names)...

Comment: Well if you inspect the output panel in Plunker, you can see what it's done. It has created endpoints for those files on their servers, and it renders `<script>` and `<link>` elements that have references to the files on their servers.

Comment: I see... they save those files in their server, then they replace the filename in `<script>` and `<link>` by their path... is it really as simple as that? Why does [live preview of brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Live-Preview-Overview) look so complicated?

Comment: Well I am not familiar with that particular tool but it appears that brackets is a full-featured editor, that not only echos those pages back to the user, but also parses, formats, etc.